# file format not recognized; treating as linker script

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, g++

I am trying to compile and my project using this make file:

```
GLFLAGS=-lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lxi
CC=g++

window.o: window.h window.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(GLFLAGS)
main.o: window.h main.cpp
   $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(GLFLAGS)
all: window.o main.o
   $(CC) $^ -o main
```

but I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:window.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:window.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

both main.cpp and window.cpp are dependent on a class I made in window.h.

Comment: What are the compilation commands that result from your makefile? You can abstract your makefile from this entirely and thus get closer to determining the problem (n. "debugging")

Comment: `g++ -c window.h -o main.o   
g++  window.o main.o -o main  
/usr/bin/ld:window.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:window.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
`

Comment: And the command that creates `window.o`? And why are you building `.h` files? What builds `main.cpp`? This should all be in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flags are not used in the right place. `-l` flags are **linker flags** and used only at link-time.

Using the right variables, and adding some to clarify, you can change your makefile to :

```
EXE     :=  main
SRC     :=  main.cpp window.cpp
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
LDLIBS  :=  -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lxi

.PHONY: all

all:    $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

If you need auto-dependencies generation, add this :

```
EXE     :=  main
SRC     :=  main.cpp window.cpp
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEP     :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)

LDLIBS      :=  -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lxi
CPPFLAGS    :=  -MMD -MP

.PHONY: all

all:    $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

-include $(DEP)
```

Comment: now I am getting compile errors. That the class I made in window.h is not declared.